# Exact Hom-sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $0\to Y'\xrightarrow {\lambda} Y\xrightarrow {\mu} Y''$ be a sequence of modules such that for all $ X $, 
$$0\to\hom (X, Y')\to\hom (X, Y)\to\hom (X, Y'') $$
is exact. How can I see that $\ker\mu\subseteq\operatorname{im}\lambda $? All the rest concernig left-exactness was clear to me.

Comment: If you take $X = R$ (the ring), then you recover the original sequence

Comment: @zcn: I verified your claim, the necessary diagrams commuting, etc. Two questions arose: 1: The proof reminded me of Yoneda's Lemma. Is this indeed a special case? 2. Does the same trick work for the contravariant Hom-Functor? Thank you.

Comment: As to question 1: yes, this is a special case of Yoneda's Lemma, in the form $M \cong \text{Hom}_R(R, M)$ canonically. For question 2: the same trick does not work exactly, as one does not recover the original sequence, but rather its dual. If there is a dualizing object (not necessarily $R$ itself) in the category of $R$-modules, then one can dualize twice, to recover the original. I'm not sure about the general case though